# R namespaces: how to get imports packages when installing and loading R packages from fresh R install.

Tags: r, namespaces, install.packages

I have set up a fresh R and RStudio on a new Win7 x64. When I want to install and load packages (from within RStudio) errors seems to pop up that seems to be related to the packages namespace imports directive. For instance scales when trying to load ggplot2 (with some danish in between):

```
> install.packages('ggplot2')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/ggplot2_1.0.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2675576 bytes (2.6 MB)
opened URL
downloaded 2.6 MB

package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpodrNFq\downloaded_packages
> library(ggplot2)
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/scales/R/scales.rdb': No such file or directory
Error: indlæsning af pakke eller navnerum fejlede for ‘ggplot2’
```

Would I need to do ´install.packages()´ for package scales (and all other missing packages) or is there a way to have this done more automated when you have a fresh R install.

Surely, I do not grasp the concept of namespaces of the packages and have tried to read other SO questions like[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371181/namespaces-in-r-packages) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861014/problems-installing-r-packages) - and ultimately run the risk of a dublicated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the DESCRIPTION file you see:

```
Depends: R (>= 2.14), stats, methods
Imports: plyr (>= 1.7.1), digest, grid, gtable (>= 0.1.1), reshape2,
        scales (>= 0.2.3), proto, MASS
```

So you are probably seeing a side-effect of not having installed the `scales` package. You can either look at the DESCRIPTION file using your file browser or by executing:

```
 help(pac=ggplot2)   # and click on the DESCRIPTION file link at the top of that page.
```

Comment: Yes, I figured that I dont have the packages mentioned in the Imports (since its a fresh windows and R install). And I also figured that I need to install them. My question was whether this should be done manunally with import.packages() for all the missing "Imports packages"?

Comment: If you had executed `install.packages('ggplot2', dependencies=TRUE)` you might have avoided the problem. I generally have only a single library set up, so for me there is no ambiguity about where things should go, but you may need to specify a `'lib'` argument since you got that warning.

Comment: However, I do not know how to specify .libPaths() to only one place when  using RStudio. Seems like RStudio insists on having libs at both the "C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/3.1" and "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.3/library" directories. How to change this behaviour (tried to specify .libPaths() within .Rprofile  - didnt work.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `install.packages('ggplot2', lib=.libPaths()[2], dependencies=TRUE)`? (If the C:/User/ libPath is first then you might swap the 2 with a 1.)

Comment: Thats a very nice workaround. Very intuitive - I'll take that for sure